# how to query Datetime object by date?

Tags: sql-server-2008

i want to query a table according to a particular date, but the problem is the datatype of that field is datetime

```
select  * from  Supplier  where modified_Date='2011-05-07 12:52:16.830'
```

this query is returning result

but

```
 select  * from  Supplier  where modified_Date='2011-05-07'
```

there is no result

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SQL Server 2008 has a `DATE` data type. You can cast your `DATETIME` to `DATE` and perform the comparison.

```
SELECT *
FROM   Supplier
WHERE  CAST(Modified_Date AS DATE) = '2011-05-07'
```

Reference: [DateTime TransactSQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

You have to allow for the time component because `2011-05-07 <> 2011-05-07 12:52:16.830`

Either change to a range type query

```
select  * from  Supplier  where
   modified_Date >= '2011-05-07' 
   and
   modified_Date < '2011-05-08'
```

...or cast to date since you're using SQL Server 2008

```
select  * from  Supplier  where
   CAST(modified_Date AS date) = '2011-05-07'
```

From a performance perspective, use the first one. Or have an indexed computed column that does the CAST for you and you filter on this

Comment: From a performance perspective SQL Server 2008 will convert the 2nd one into something like the first one anyway.

Comment: @Martin: does it? Can't test right now. Thought of this though https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/653206/the-optimizer-should-be-able-to-understand-the-invertability-of-built-in-intrinsics-on-dates-for-the-purposes-of-index-sargability

Comment: Yes it adds a compute scalar to the plan giving both ends of the range to seek. See http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/526431/make-more-functions-sargable

Answer (score 1):

Just to post an alternative syntax to gbn's answer, you can also use `BETWEEN`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Supplier
WHERE modified_Date BETWEEN '2011-05-07' AND '2011-05-07 23:59:59:999'
```

**EDIT:** You have to specify the end time as `BETWEEN` defaults to midnight which would return additional rows in this case.

From [BOL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187922.aspx):

> BETWEEN returns TRUE if the value of
>   test_expression is greater than or
>   equal to the value of begin_expression
>   and less than or equal to the value of
>   end_expression.

Comment: `BETWEEN` will return the wrong results. It will include `'2011-05-08 00:00:00`

Comment: Apologies, you are correct, `BETWEEN` will include midnight on the 8th. Have edited my answer to reflect that, it does make the query ugly :)

Comment: Your answer still won't work as `'2011-05-07 23:59:59:999'` gets rounded up to `'2011-05-08 00:00:00:000'`. `Between` is best avoided for this type of query.

Comment: As Nighil is using SQL Server 2008 I was expecting `DATETIME2` to be used (as recommended by MS). To use it with DATETIME change the last 9 to a 7. But this is getting messy so, as you say, it's probably best to avoid `BETWEEN` in this scenario. I was going to delete my answer but I think I'll leave it to help others avoid falling in to the same trap as I did :)

Comment: @Tony - The OP states in the question `datetime`. Even if there were on `datetime2(x)` the most correct thing to use would depend on the value of `x`. For `datetime2(7)` you would need 7 decimal places.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the column into date in your select query will bring the results.