# SQL Server Joining 3 Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please help me, below is my sql query. When I execute it, the result is nothing.

```
SELECT tblclientinfo.acctnum, 
       tblclientinfo.fname, 
       tblclientinfo.fname, 
       tblreservation.unitnum, 
       tblbillingsched.billnum, 
       tblbillingsched.duedate, 
       tblbillingsched.monthlyamort, 
       tblbillingsched.totalbalance 
FROM   tblclientinfo 
       JOIN tblreservation 
         ON tblclientinfo.acctnum = tblreservation.reservationnum 
       JOIN tblbillingsched 
         ON tblreservation.reservationnum = tblbillingsched.accountnum 
WHERE  tblbillingsched.accountnum = 'C0000000021' 
       AND tblbillingsched.duedate BETWEEN '1/1/2014' AND '1/30/2014'
```

Here are my tables:

```
tblClientInfo, pk = acctNum
tblReservation, pk = ReservationNum, fk = accountNum
tblBillingSched, pk = ID,  fk = accountNum
```

Comment: Are you sure you have data that meets those filters?

Comment: Thanks guys for your prompt reply but the result is still empty. I double check every table and all of them have data. I think my pk and fk is the problem but I don't know how to fix it. Please see my table relationship picture. [link](http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5520/9950519065_06207ec31e_z.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for...

```
SELECT tblclientinfo.acctnum, 
       tblclientinfo.fname, 
       tblclientinfo.fname, 
       tblreservation.unitnum, 
       tblbillingsched.billnum, 
       tblbillingsched.duedate, 
       tblbillingsched.monthlyamort, 
       tblbillingsched.totalbalance 
FROM   tblclientinfo 
       JOIN tblreservation 
         ON tblclientinfo.acctnum = tblreservation.accountnum 
       JOIN tblbillingsched 
         ON tblclientinfo.acctnum = tblbillingsched.accountnum 
WHERE  tblbillingsched.accountnum = 'C0000000021' 
       AND tblbillingsched.duedate BETWEEN '1/1/2014' AND '1/30/2014'
```

[See a demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/776ba/1)

Comment: @harifx, my tblbillingsched.duedate data type is date only.

Comment: This is your 999th answer :D The next answer that you post will be your 1000th

Comment: @Doorknob [Here's #1000](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19095318/row-number-over-where-rownumber-between)

Answer (score 0):

Your first join is wrong. In the table tblReservation the foreignkey is accountNum an you make the join with the field reservationnum.
The code should be this:

```
SELECT tblclientinfo.acctnum, 
    `tblclientinfo.fname, 
     tblclientinfo.fname, 
     tblreservation.unitnum, 
     tblbillingsched.billnum, 
     tblbillingsched.duedate, 
     tblbillingsched.monthlyamort, 
     tblbillingsched.totalbalance 
FROM tblclientinfo 
     JOIN tblreservation 
     ON tblclientinfo.acctnum = tblreservation.accountNum 
     JOIN tblbillingsched 
     ON tblreservation.reservationnum = tblbillingsched.accountnum 
WHERE  tblbillingsched.accountnum = 'C0000000021' 
       AND tblbillingsched.duedate BETWEEN '1/1/2014' AND '1/30/2014'
```

Answer (score 0):

Is DueDate a Date time field Try the following and see if it works:

CAST(tblbillingsched.duedate AS DATE) BETWEEN '1/1/2014' AND '1/30/2014'

Check out this post for a more detailed discussion:

[how to query Datetime object by date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6095542/how-to-query-datetime-object-by-date)

Answer (score 0):

(off topic and probably not the answer but I thought worth noting)

The safer form of this:

```
tblbillingsched.duedate BETWEEN '1/1/2014' AND '1/30/2014'
```

is this:

```
tblbillingsched.duedate >= '20140101' AND 
tblbillingsched.duedate <'20140130'
```

Stating a date like this `'20140130'` is unmistakable.