# Row_Number Over Where RowNumber between

Tags: sql-server

I'm try to select a certain rows from my table using the row_number over. However, the sql will prompt the error msg "Invalid column name 'ROWNUMBERS' ". Anyone can correct me?

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY  Price ASC) AS ROWNUMBERS, * 
FROM Product
WHERE  ROWNUMBERS BETWEEN  @fromCount AND @toCount
```

Comment: It's definitely not MySQL.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Attempting to reference the aliased column in the `WHERE` clause does not work because of the logical query processing taking place. The `WHERE` is evaluated before the `SELECT` clause. Therefore, the column `ROWNUMBERS` does not exist when `WHERE` is evaluated.

The correct way to reference the column in this example would be:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM
    (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY  Price ASC) AS ROWNUMBERS, * 
    FROM Product) a
WHERE a.ROWNUMBERS BETWEEN @fromCount AND @toCount
```

For your reference, the order for operations is:

1. `FROM`
2. `WHERE`
3. `GROUP BY`
4. `HAVING`
5. `SELECT`
6. `ORDER BY`

Answer (score 2):

There is another answer here that solves the specific error reported. However, I also want to address the wider problem. It looks a lot like what you are doing here is *paging* your results for display. If that is the case, and if you can use Sql Server 2012, there is a better way now. Take a look at [`OFFSET/FETCH`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699618.aspx):

```
SELECT First Name + ' ' + Last Name 
FROM Employees 
ORDER BY First Name 
OFFSET 10 ROWS FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY;
```

That would show the third page of a query where the page size is 5.