# ROW_NUMBER() Sql error

Tags: sql-server-2008

i am working on my project and i have to create a sql query  to achieve my aims. but unfortunately i get an error when i run the query.

**here is my Sql query :**

```
select ROW_NUMBER() 
OVER (ORDER BY Advertisement.AdsDate asc ) AS AdsIndex 
,Advertisement.AdsId , Advertisement.AdsEnTitle from Advertisement
where Advertisement.Status=N'True' and AdsIndex<=17 and AdsIndex>=11
```

**Error :**

> Invalid column name 'AdsIndex'.

How should i solve my problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can not get **Rowno** in Where clause.you have to **cte or subquery** or

```
with cte as
(
select ROW_NUMBER() 
OVER (ORDER BY Advertisement.AdsDate asc ) AS AdsIndex 
,Advertisement.AdsId , Advertisement.AdsEnTitle from Advertisement
where Advertisement.Status=N'True' 
)

select * from cte where  AdsIndex between 11 and 17
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't reference a `ROW_NUMBER` in the where clause. See this relevant post:

[SQL Row_Number() function in Where Clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466963/sql-row-number-function-in-where-clause)

Try wrapping the query above in a CTE or subquery and filtering from there.

EDIT: More background here:

[Row_Number Over Where RowNumber between](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19095318/row-number-over-where-rownumber-between)

Answer (score 1):

Use a subquery:

```
;with cte as(
             select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY AdsDate asc ) AS AdsIndex, 
                    AdsId, 
                    AdsEnTitle 
             from Advertisement
             where Status=N'True')
select * from cte
where AdsIndex<=17 and AdsIndex>=11
```

Or:

```
select * from (select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY AdsDate asc ) AS AdsIndex, 
                    AdsId, 
                    AdsEnTitle 
               from Advertisement
               where Status=N'True') as cte
where AdsIndex<=17 and AdsIndex>=11
```

Comment: it says : The multi-part identifier "cte.Status" could not be bound !